# Angular 9, scroll restoration/anchor scrolling does not work with async data loading

Tags: angular, asynchronous, anchor

I am trying to scroll to an anchor after navigating by routerlink using fragments.

** Component 1 **

```
<a routerLink="/training/{{ currentTrainingId }}" fragment="{{currentDomainId}}">
```

This link should bring the user to component 2. I hoped to achieve anchor scrolling by giving the element an id and then automatically adding #id in the URL using fragments.

** Component 2 **

```
<div *ngIf="all data has been loaded">
    ....
    <domain-overview *ngFor="let domain of domains" [id]="domain.id"></domain-overview>
</div>
```

The generated URL does seem to be right.

```
http://localhost:4200/training/28#40
```

However, the anchor scrolling does not happen. I think it has something to do with asynchronously loading data. The domains have not loaded yet when anchor scrolling is executed..

I have created a static div and then the anchor scrolling works.

Does anyone have any idea how to deal with async data and anchor scrolling?

## Solution

Do not rely on the automatic anchor scrolling, but instead program your own scroll function. Based on @Vinaayakh his answers I got the following working solution.

```
scroll(id){
    const elmnt = document.getElementById(id);
    elmnt.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
}

this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
  this.fragment = fragment;
});
```

Later, after loading all data in the complete section of the subscription, I call the scroll function.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.scroll(this.fragment);
 }, 250);
```

Comment: Have you tried the code without *ngIf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this function

```
scroll(id){
    const elmnt = document.getElementById(id);
    elmnt.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
}
```

and add the function to HTML

```
<domain-overview *ngFor="let domain of domains" (click)="scroll(id)" [id]="domain.id"></domain-overview>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But won't this scroll to the domain when someone clicks on the domain? I want to scroll to the domain when the user comes back to the page based on the id that is in the url.

Comment: Are they in the same component or different?

Comment: Different components. I will try to clarify that in the question.

Comment: If you have some dynamic data comming in after the page is loaded, you could try calling the scroll() function after the page has loaded with the current route params instead of on click

Comment: Oh thanks a lot dude! I got it to work :D. I did have to add a timeout.

Comment: It is best not to add a timeout. If possible try calling the function after the dynamic data is obtained.

Comment: Yea I did that at first but I need a small delay to let the loaded data actually render on the page. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Update to include ActivatedRoute.snapshot (property) you can use without subscribing to the route fragment:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
    this.fragment = this.route.snapshot.fragment
}
```

Then in your ngOnInit:

```
if(!!this.fragment){
    this.scroll(this.fragment)
}
```

You can throw the if statement inside a setTimeout if needed, but this simplifies the code while not needing the unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy.